# Zeppelin notebook execute not manual

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, spark-submit

is there a way to execute the spark code in a zeppelin notebook, without having to do it interactively? I'm looking for something specific or if anyone could point me in the correct direction. Or alternatively, other ways to submit spark code, which is currently in a zeppelin notebook.  The reason I can't use spark-submit is that there is no command line access due to security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeppelin provides REST API which, among other functions, can be used to run either individual paragraphs, either [synchronously](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-synchronously)

```
http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/run/[noteId]/[paragraphId]
```

or [asynchronously](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-asynchronously)

```
http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/job/[noteId]/[paragraphId]
```

as well as [whole notebook](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-all-paragraphs):

```
http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/job/[noteId]
```

It is also possible to define CRON jobs, both from notebook itself and from the REST API.